# Updating other charts on dc_leaflet zoom or pan

Tags: leaflet, dc.js, crossfilter

I have a `dc_leaflet.markerChart` and another `barChart`. How do I make the `markerChart` update the other charts (dataTable, barChart etc) that are linked when there is zooming or panning on the map?

They are using the same crossfilter and the map updates when any of the bars are clicked. How do I make it work the other way round as well?

Answer (score 2):

Actually figured it out. "filterByArea(true)" does just that!

```
dc_leaflet.markerChart(...).filterByArea(true)
```